# Need T-SQL code for the following pseudo code

Tags: t-sql

```
Table A: | BillToName | Current| Total |
          -----------------------------
         | Company29  | N      | 100   |
          -----------------------------
         | Company02  | Y      | 80    |
          -----------------------------
```

I need T-SQL for the following pseudo code:

SELECT BillToName, SUM(Total *regardless if the status is "Y" or "N") WHERE Current = 'Y'

Feel free to ask questions. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the where statement?

Comment: Seeing SUM means that one company may show up more than once? If so what does "Current = 'Y'" refer to? At least one row with 'Y'?

Comment: I need the WHERE statement because I want to output the BillToName "where" Current = Y. At all times there will only be one BillToName with Current set to Y, all the other BillToNames will have Current set to N. There will never be duplicate BillToNames. Thanks!

Comment: @Bruno - I encourage you to repost your question but take into consideration following adjustments: **1.** Concoct a more complete sample of input values. For example, add a Company30 with a Y and a N. **2.** Show us what the output should be, not merely convey this through comments. **3.** Don't take an hour or more to respond to comments. It makes it look like you've left. If other posters are anywhere like me (let's hope not;), they all revisited the question several times to look for new information when there is none, a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean something like:

```
SELECT BillToName, SUM(Total) 
FROM Table
WHERE BillToName IN (SELECT BillToName FROM Table WHERE Current = 'Y')
GROUP BY BillToName
```

Comment: +1 because I think you are right but OP left way to much to speculate. Viewing the amount of *different* responses seems to back this up. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.BillToName, b.Total
FROM TableA a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Total) Total FROM TableA) b
WHERE Current = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select billtoname,(select sum(total) from table)
where current='Y'
```